# SharePoint 2013 BCS using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, bcs

I would like to customise the BCS on AngularJS or JS and HTML, is that possible?
Could you provide some guidance and references please.
I tried google could not get what I want.

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code? If so, could you please share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution, you can expose the SQL data as web service (odata/REST) using Web Api and create SharePoint hosted app to consume the data and do CRUD operation.